# NSAssert and release

Tags: objective-c

Can I use this string in release code?

```
NSAssert([entity buildEntity], @"Building failed at entity with id: %d", entity.entityId);
```

[entity buildEntity] returns BOOL and must be called.

So the question is: if I turn off assertion in release(default behavior of Xcode 4) then will blocks of code inside assertion be executed or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO, `buildEntity` will not execute in release mode.
Use below code, this will behave same in debug and release mode.

```
id lValue = [entity buildEntity];
NSAssert(lValue, @"Building failed at entity with id: %d", entity.entityId);
```